# How to import Java Libraries in Robot Framework, If I am trying to test Java code from it

Tags: java, macos, automation, robotframework, jython

I have made a entire project with the following files and code(java) on Mac OS (Intel chip), all are in the same directory. I am running the example.robot  on terminal(command robot example.robot
) but getting the following output.

Can anyone suggest how to do I get it to work or anything I have missed here in code?

**example.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     A test suite for valid login.
...
...               Keywords are imported from the resource file
Resource          resource.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Create Java Folder
```

**resource.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Reusable keywords and variables.
Library           SampleKeywordsLibrary

*** Keywords ***
Create Java Folder
    create_folder_java
```

**SampleKeywordsLibrary.java**

```
import java.io.File;



public class SampleKeywordsLibrary {

  public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";
  public void create_folder_java() {
    String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String path = currentDirectory + "/SampleFolderJava";
    //Instantiate the File class
    File f1 = new File(path);
    //Creating a folder using mkdir() method
    boolean bool = f1.mkdir();
  }

}
```

**Output**

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'robotTest/src/main/java/resource.robot' on line 3: Importing library 'SampleKeywordsLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SampleKeywordsLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
==============================================================================
Example :: A test suite for valid login.                                      
==============================================================================
Valid Login                                                           | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'create_folder_java' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example :: A test suite for valid login.                              | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  robotTest/src/main/java/output.xml
Log:     robotTest/src/main/java/log.html
Report:  robotTest/src/main/java/report.html
```

Comment: Is your installation of robotframework using jython? The normal python version of robot can't import java code. The error implies you're using python, not jython.

Answer (score 0):

The library import was not successful and you are not able to use your keyword. Have a look at the documentation on how to [import](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-library-to-import).
The most foolproof solution is to use absolute path to your library.
eg.:

```
*** Settings ***    
Library    /absolute/path/JavaLibrary.java
```

try using current directory variable from system [variables](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#operating-system-variables)

Comment: A python-based robot framework installation won't be able to import a java file.

Comment: @BryanOakley that is a good point i didnt notice that at all.